# CSS3 Perspective() animation acting weird on fast mouse move

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, animation, opera

**Perspective animation**
I was playing around with the `css` `perspective()` animation. However, when testing it in Chrome and Opera, I came across some weird behavior.

Chrome and Opera are acting very weird when repeatedly hovering fast over the `animation`. The `animation` gets triggered on `:hover`. Perhaps this is causing the behavior? How can i stop Chrome and Opera having this behavior.

**Fiddle**
I reproduced the problem within a fiddle. Just do like the **red dot** is showing.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.perspective {
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: transform .33s;
}

.perspective:hover {
  transform: perspective( 800px ) rotateY(15deg);
}

.perspective p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}

.mouse-helper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 90px;
  width: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.mouse-helper .animated {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  animation: up-down .29s infinite;
}

@keyframes up-down {
  0% {bottom: 0;top: calc(100% - 15px);}
  50% {top: 0;bottom: calc(100% - 15px);}
  100% { bottom: 0;top: calc(100% - 15px); }
}
```

```html
<h2>Move with you mouse over the box like the red DOT does.</h2>
<p>You will see that the `perspective` animation will act very wierd on Chrome and Opera. On firefox and IE it works fine.</p>
<p>NOTE: Don't do it over the red dot itself, do it near the dot or any other size of the shape.</p>
<div class="container">
  <div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="perspective">
      <p>TEXT</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mouse-helper">
    <div class="animated"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess, but it's only a guess, is that this is related to the response in [this issue thread](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=339273), where some transforms are hardware accelerated and some are not, and that can cause things to get out of sync briefly.

If you explicitly add `transform: perspective(0px) rotateY(0deg);` to your (non-`hover`ed) `.perspective`, it doesn't happen:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.perspective {
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: transform .33s;
  transform: perspective(0px) rotateY(0deg);
}

.perspective:hover {
  transform: perspective( 800px ) rotateY(15deg);
}

.perspective p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}

.mouse-helper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 90px;
  width: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.mouse-helper .animated {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  animation: up-down .29s infinite;
}

@keyframes up-down {
  0% {bottom: 0;top: calc(100% - 15px);}
  50% {top: 0;bottom: calc(100% - 15px);}
  100% { bottom: 0;top: calc(100% - 15px); }
}
```

```html
<h2>Move with you mouse over the box like the red DOT does.</h2>
<p>You will see that the `perspective` animation will act very wierd on Chrome and Opera. On firefox and IE it works fine.</p>
<p>NOTE: Don't do it over the red dot itself, do it near the dot or any other size of the shape.</p>
<div class="container">
  <div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="perspective">
      <p>TEXT</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mouse-helper">
    <div class="animated"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So there's your fix; as to the "why?", once again a guess: The Chromium issue linked above has this from a Chromium dev:

> Alternatively we may be able to pull transform animations back to the main thread in this case.
>
> We already do this (at least in M33) for animations where keyframes reference both accelerated and non-accelerated properties:

Maybe the same is now true for transitions (the issue is from 2014), but because the non-hover state does not have *any* transforms, this logic won't be triggered in your case.

Comment: Well seen sir, when adding declaring the `perspective` first onto the class itself, it indeed does what its suppose to do!